# Issue with ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a class that is set to be an ObservableObject:

```
class MatchData : Identifiable,  ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var id: Int
    
    @Published var LocalPlayer: Player
    @Published var RemotePlayer: Player
    
    init(_ match: GKTurnBasedMatch, id: Int) {
        
        let local = match.participants[0].player!
        let remote = match.participants[1].player ?? GKPlayer()
        //self.id = match.matchID
        
        LocalPlayer = Player(Alias: local.alias
            , DisplayName: local.displayName
            , TeamPlayerId: local.teamPlayerID
            , PlayerId: local.gamePlayerID
        )
        
        RemotePlayer = Player(Alias: remote.alias
            , DisplayName: remote.displayName
            , TeamPlayerId: remote.teamPlayerID
            , PlayerId: remote.gamePlayerID
            
        )
        self.id  = id
    }
}
```

and then in a different class I have:

```
@ObservedObject var MatchList: [MatchData] = [MatchData]()
```

However, this produces the error:

> Generic struct 'ObservedObject' requires that '[MatchData]' conform to
> 'ObservableObject'

I believed my class to conform to ObservableObject, however I do not seem to be able to get rid of this error.

Comment: You cannot makes array, [MatchData], as observed object property, because it is not observable. Only observable can be observed, like `@ObservedObject var matchData: MatchData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make explicit observable class for collection of `MatchData`, like

```
class MatchList: ObservableObject {
   @Published var data: [MatchData] = [MatchData]()
}
```

and then you will be able to use in view

```
@ObservedObject var matchList: MatchList
```

Comment: Thanks,  I tried 
`    class MatchList : ObservableObject {
        @Published var data: [MatchData] = [MatchData]()
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var matchList: MatchList`

But this still produces the same error

**Edit - ignore me, I needed to remove the ObservableObject declaration in the MatchData class

Comment: It can't be same error if code changed... look all places - something forgotten.